# How to use erase() function to erase a vector by indexing?

Tags: c++, vector

To traverse a vector array normally, I use indexing(see code) instead of using an iterator. Today, I have tried to erase a vector element by indexing. I have tried several times and several ways, but each time there seems to be an error  in the last line(in the compiler).
Please help me fix the code to erase an element by indexing. Thanks in advance.

```
vector<pair<int, pair<int, int> > > p;

p.push_back(make_pair(1,make_pair(2,4))) ;
p.push_back(make_pair(5,make_pair(6,7))) ;

for(int i = 0; i != p.size(); i++)
    if(p[i].first == 1)
        p.erase(i);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
for(int i = 0; i != p.size(); ) // Don't increment here.
{
    if(p[i].first == 1)
    {
        p.erase(p.begin() + i );
    }
    else
    {
       ++i;
    }
}
```

but it will be more idiomatic to use:

```
for ( auto iter = p.begin(); iter != p.end(); )
{
    if( iter->first == 1 )
    {
        iter = p.erase(iter);
    }
    else
    {
       ++iter;
    }
}
```

Better still, use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

```
p.erase(std::remove_if(p.begin(), p.end(),
                       [](std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>> const& item) { return item.first == 1;}),
        v.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not starightforward to make your code work as your indexing with `i` will be broken when you erase element - you need to increase `i` only when element is not erased.

```
for(int i = 0; i != p.size(); )
    if(p[i].first == 1)
        p.erase(p.begin() + i);
    else
       i++;
```

but you better use `erase-remove` idiom, as it is less error prone and more efficient (erasing in middle of vector is quite expensive):

```
p.erase( std::remove_if( p.begin(), p.end(), []( const auto &pair ) { return pair.first == 1; } ), p.end() );
```

[`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)